# How to preview posts on single page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**Hi,**

*this is my code in react js*

I want to show my blog posts on single page on clicking read more button I pick this url from
news api and i want to show every pot by its specific id but i use url as id

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import BlogPage from "./BlogPage";
import propTypes from "prop-types";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

export default class blogPost extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    category: "general",
  };
  static propTypes = {
    category: propTypes.string,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
    };
    /* document.title = `${this.props.category}-news `; */
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let url = 
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsData);
    this.setState({
      articles: parsData.articles,
      totalResults: parsData.totalResults,
    });
  }

  getMorePost = async () => {
    let url = 
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsData);
    this.setState({ articles: this.state.articles.concat(parsData.articles) });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          {/* <span style={{ color: "grey" }}>
                Blogs 
                <span style={{ fontWeight: "500", color: "black" }}>
                  - {this.props.category}
                </span>
              </span> */}

          <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={this.state.articles.length}
            next={getMorePost}
            hasMore={this.state.articles.length !== this.state.totalResults}
            loader={<h3> Loading...</h3>}
            endMessage={<h4>Nothing more to show</h4>}
          >
            <div className="row pt-3.">
              {this.state.articles.map((element) => {
                return (
                  <div className={this.props.BlogClass} key={element.url}>
                    <BlogPage
                      CardClass={this.props.ClassCard}
                      ClassDes={this.props.DesClass}
                      ClassTitle={(this.props.TitleClass, " heading-blog")}
                      CardBody={this.props.BodyCard}
                      imgStyle={this.props.styleImg}
                      CardStyle={{
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%",
                        padding: "10px 0",
                        border: "none",
                      }}
                      title={element.title ? element.title.slice(0, 45) : ""}
                      description={
                        element.description
                          ? element.description.slice(0, 90)
                          : ""
                      }
                      author={
                        /* element.author? element.author.slice(0, 5) : "" */
                        element.category
                      }
                      img={element.urlToImage}
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show this posts on this page by clicking the read more button i try it several times but don't understand it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import BlogPost from "./BlogPost";

export default function Blogpreview() {
  /* const [blog,setBlog]=useState()


    useEffect(() => {
        let blog = articles.find((blog) => blog.id === parseInt(id));
        if (blog) {
          setBlog(blog);
        }
    }, []) */

  /* const [blog,setBlog]=useState(null)


    useState = async () =>{
        let url = 
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsData);
    setBlog({ articles: parsData.articles,
      totalResults: parsData.totalResults
     });
    }
 */

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="col-6 BlogPreviewBox px-5 ">
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img className="display-blog-box my-5" src="/"></img>
        </div>
        <h1 className="blog-preview-heading">
          Why invoicing are beneficial for your business{/* {blog.title} */}
        </h1>
        <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
          <span className="text-center py-3">07 December 2021</span>
          <button className="btn-blog-display">2 min read</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="row display-blog-content-row">
        {/*  <div className="col-3">
               { <div>
                    <p >What is Olabooks?</p>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                        <span>How to add invoice in Olabooks?</span>
                        <span className="py-2">How to share invoice in Olabooks?</span>
                    </div>
                    <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
                </div>}
            </div> */}
        <div className="col-6">
          <div className="d-flex flex-column display-blog-text">
            <div>
              <span>
                Businesses that adopt advanced technologies are more likely to
                thrive in the long run because of the rapid response to modern
                techniques and innovation. Many questions need to be taken into
                account while adopting advanced technology, but most
                importantly, you begin to think about the values it must provide
                to you and your business. It is not an easy task toruna
                business, especially in this tech-savvy world. Let's dig into
                some commercial benefits of moving from pen and paper invoicing
                to efficient e-invoicing that would make headway for your
                business.
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="tag-display-blog">
            <div>
              <strong>By Olabooks</strong>
              <span>author</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*  <div className="col-3">
                <div>
                    <span>Related</span>
                </div>
                <div className="displa-related-blog">
                    <h5 className="py-2">Why is e-invoicing beneficial for your business?</h5>
                    <span>
                        Business that adopt advanced technologies are more likely to thrive in the long run because of
                    </span>
                    <button className="btn-related-blog-display">9 min read</button>
                </div>
            </div> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Where is the "Read More" button? And how does `BlogPreview` relate to `BlogPost`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried making API calls to the same URL, it seems that you are **getting same API response in both cases (with and without pageSize param)**, due to which, **your "read more" is actually not rendering any new content to the screen**

[image]

(with the pageSize query parameter)

[image]

(without the pageSize parameter)

*Also, it is better to not include your API key in the question*

Comment: If you're referring to `totalResults` that's the total number of articles irrespective of the `pageSize` value. If you check the actual number of `articles` returned, you'll see there's only 20 items (`pageSize` value) in the first call.